# View Controllers not being presented correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

When the function is done executing I want to go back to my ProfileTabViewController. I want to get sent back to the view controller keeping the ProfileTabViewControllers same navigation bar and UITabBarController from before. The way I have it now it gets sent to the ProfileTavViewController but I lose my navigation bar as well as the tab bar. How do I just send it back to the original ProfileTabViewController. The first image is the original ViewController and the second image is when it gets sent back.

[image: original ProfileTabViewController]
[image: When i get sent back]

```
@IBAction func updateAction(_ sender: Any) {
     let newInterests = options.joined(separator: " , ")

    if newInterests == ""{
        showAlert(message: "Please select at least one interest.")
    }else{
       updateFunction()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileTabViewController") as! UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you dismissing the view controller when you go back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Presenting a ViewController it will not show navigationbar beacause presentation depends on UIViewController not NavigationViewcontroller.

You have to use popViewController method to get navigation bar.

```
for controller in self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
  if controller is ProfileViewController {
    self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
    break
}
```

}
//Use Pop

Comment: Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'push'

Comment: the tabBar that was originally showing still doesn't show, and I do not want the ability to swipe back to the previous screen. Is there any way I can just get sent back to the original ProfileTabViewController without any changes.

Comment: See Edited Answer

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!